# Set pitch back to 0% (Original BPM) in Traktor

Tags: software, dj, traktor

I have a track in Traktor that has its pitch -10.3%. I want to make it snap back to 0%. Is there a way to do this without manually pulling the pitch fader back to the middle of its range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can double click the pitch fader to reset it to 0.

You can also assign the pitch fader reset action to a key in your keyboard or a control surface.

1) Preferences -> Control Manager -> Add in... -> Tempo -> Tempo Fader
[image: Traktor Control Manager 1]

2) Select the new created controller, and in interaction mode select "reset". In assignment select which deck you want to tempo fader reset.

3) In device mapping click "learn" and press the key (keyboard or control surface) that you want to trigger the tempo fader reset.

[image: Traktor Control Manager 2]

Now that key will reset the tempo fader to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, this is no longer the answer as Traktor changed its menus! To reset tempo back to 0 with a button, I had to go into Add In>Deck Common>Tempo Adjust. NEXT, I had to assign a midi key. Without this, I couldn't do the next step, change the Type of Controller to BUTTON. Then, Set to value = 0.